# How to remove \r from the output of a command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a script that uses Docker as much as possible.

Here is an excerpt:

```
fecha=`docker run -t --rm alpine date +%y-%m-%d_%H-%M`
tag=$fecha-$var
```

On one hand, it doesn't work because fecha contains a \r character.
On the other hand this DOES work:

```
fecha=`date +%y-%m-%d_%H-%M`
tag=$fecha-$var
```

because I don't receiven a strange '\r' character.

What is the best way of doing this?

I know I could do `${fecha//\r/}`.

Comment: There is `sed`, `awk`, `tr` etc but even `${fecha//\r/}` is good enough

Comment: @davidperez : Another alternative would be to find out why your docker command produces a carriage return, and fix this.

Comment: @user1934428 I have no idea why.

Comment: In this case, I would turn *this* one into a question. And, of course, you have to tag it as _docker_ to attract the attention of people who know about this, and specify your docker configuration and, for the safe side, some details about your operating system.

Comment: Did you try: `fecha="${fecha//$'\r'/}"`

Comment: @anubhava, it works.
`echo "[$fecha]"` ==> `]20-05-22_06-20`
`echo "[${fecha//$'\r'/}]"` ==> `[20-05-22_06-20]`
Can you publish the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid calling any external utility and do this in `bash` itself:

```
fecha="${fecha//$'\r'/}"
```

In bash, words  of  the form `$'string'` are called **Backslash escape sequences**. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Examples: `$'\n'`, `$'\r'` etc